# Passing a filename to Java UDF from Pig using distributed cache

Tags: user-defined-functions, apache-pig

I am using a small map file in my Java UDF function and I want to pass the filename of this file from Pig through the constructor.

Following is the relevant part from my UDF function

```
public GenerateXML(String mapFilename) throws IOException {
    this(null);
}

public GenerateXML(String mapFilename) throws IOException {
    if (mapFilename != null) {
        // do preocessing
    }
}
```

In the Pig script I have the following line

```
DEFINE GenerateXML com.domain.GenerateXML('typemap.tsv');
```

This works in local mode, but not in distributed mode. I am passing the following parameters to Pig in command line

```
pig -Dmapred.cache.files="/path/to/typemap.tsv#typemap.tsv" -Dmapred.create.symlink=yes -f generate-xml.pig
```

And I am getting the following exception

```
2013-01-11 10:39:42,002 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: Pig script failed to parse: 
<file generate-xml.pig, line 16, column 42> Failed to generate logical plan. Nested exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: could not instantiate 'com.domain.GenerateXML' with arguments '[typemap.tsv]'
```

Any idea what I need to change to make it work?

Comment: How do you plan to use the map?  Perhaps a replicated join would get you where you need to go.

Comment: A drawback of loading the file in the constructor of the UDF is that I believe this will occur for every record the UDF processes, so you will load the file over and over and over again.

Comment: @WinnieNicklaus I think if I load the file in the constructor of UDF, then it will load only once on each node in the cluster not for every record UDF processes. If that is not the case then I might have to completely rethink the process.

Comment: I could be wrong.  But in any case, can you use a replicated join?  How will you be using the map?  How small is small?

Comment: No I can't use replicated join. My UDF has lot of business logic. The file which I am trying to put in cache is around 2.5 MB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is solved now.

It seems that when I run the Pig script using following parameters

```
pig -Dmapred.cache.files="/path/to/typemap.tsv#typemap.tsv" -Dmapred.create.symlink=yes -f generate-xml.pig
```

The `/path/to/typemap.tsv` should be the local path and not a path in HDFS.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `getCacheFiles` function in a Pig UDF and it will be enough - you don't have to use any additional properties like `mapred.cache.files`. Your case can be implemented like this:

```
public class UdfCacheExample  extends EvalFunc<Tuple> {

    private Dictionary dictionary;
    private String pathToDictionary;

    public UdfCacheExample(String pathToDictionary) {
        this.pathToDictionary = pathToDictionary;
    }

    @Override
    public Tuple exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {
        Dictionary dictionary = getDictionary();
        return createSomething(input);
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> getCacheFiles() {
        return Arrays.asList(pathToDictionary);
    }

    private Dictionary getDictionary() {
        // lazy initialization here
    }
}
```