# Using distributed cache in LoadFunc in Apache Pig

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

How can I use distributed cache in the custom data load function where I implement `LoadFunc UDF`?
In the `EvalFunc UDF` it provides a method `getCacheFiles()`.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14276749/passing-a-filename-to-java-udf-from-pig-using-distributed-cache). Alternatively, you may be able to pass in a file to add to the cache through the constructor and set it in the setLocation method. There you have access to the Job object.